# Using row.setValue in ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor

This is my code:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Import system modules
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
 
### ROTINA MÁQUINA INTERNA PERIODICIDADE: 1 DIA ###
print ('Script Rotina da Maquina Interna - Periodicidade: Rotina de 1 Dia Iniciada')

fc = 'Database Connections\\SRVSQLSIG_Producao_Vectorial.sde\\C99ROTINAS_MAQUINA_INTERNA'
name_field = 'FCDestino'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['OBJECTID','FCDestino','Ativador','Periodicidade']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if (cursor[1] == 'Email de Controlo da Maquina Interna de Rotinas') and (cursor[3] == '1 Dia'):
            print('ESTA TOP!')
            cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
            for row in cur:
                row.setValue('Ativador', 'x')
                cur.updateRow(row)

print ('Script Rotina da Maquina Interna - Periodicidade: Rotina de 1 Dia Finalizada')
```

I need that ee put only an 'x' when he respects the conditions above but he is putting in all of them.

What should I change?

Comment: Does it work if you don't use the name "`row`" for the elements of *both* the nested loops?

Comment: Your code is mixing old and new style cursors. I recommend standardizing on new style (arcpy.da) cursors.

Comment: I agree with @PolyGeo, you are mixing  the old SLOW style with the modern cursor usage and you reference cursor[1] when it should be row[1] for example. Go study the help file they have many example code snippets for you to understand syntax.

Comment: Explain what the code is supposed to do. It would also be easier to understand ifyou translate it to english

Comment: You're setting yourself up for major data corruption by nesting a deprecated UpdateCursor inside a DA SearchCursor on the same feature class. The first rule of nesting cursors is: Don't do it! Mixing cursor styles **and** editing the data midstream is a nightmare ready to happen. Your Question doesn't describe your goal, which makes it difficult to recommend a path, beyond "Stop using this code and start over again, using only DA cursors, and caching the updates until the SearchCursor completes"

Comment: You could also save a significant level of effort by using the `where_clause` parameter to restrict the query stream to just the features that meet your criteria. In fact, this looks like it could be accomplished by Calculate Field or even a simple SQL expression in an arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute cursor

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you set the same variable "row" for the nested for loop.

Fix it this way below that should solve it, in addition to correcting it with the suggestions of using the latest form of loops with **[arcpy.da](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/what-is-the-data-access-module-.htm)**

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Import system modules
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
 
### ROTINA MÁQUINA INTERNA PERIODICIDADE: 1 DIA ###
print ('Script Rotina da Maquina Interna - Periodicidade: Rotina de 1 Dia Iniciada')

fc = 'Database Connections\\SRVSQLSIG_Producao_Vectorial.sde\\C99ROTINAS_MAQUINA_INTERNA'
name_field = 'FCDestino'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['OBJECTID','FCDestino','Ativador','Periodicidade']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if (cursor[1] == 'Email de Controlo da Maquina Interna de Rotinas') and (cursor[3] == '1 Dia'):
            print('ESTA TOP!')
            cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
            for upd_row in cur:
                upd_row.setValue('Ativador', 'x')
                cur.updateRow(upd_row)

print ('Script Rotina da Maquina Interna - Periodicidade: Rotina de 1 Dia Finalizada')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of comments about nested cursors, which I agree with, but I think a single cursor will work.

```py
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Import system modules
import arcpy
 
### ROTINA MÁQUINA INTERNA PERIODICIDADE: 1 DIA ###
print ('Script Rotina da Maquina Interna - Periodicidade: Rotina de 1 Dia Iniciada')

fc = 'Database Connections\\SRVSQLSIG_Producao_Vectorial.sde\\C99ROTINAS_MAQUINA_INTERNA'
name_field = 'FCDestino'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['OBJECTID','FCDestino','Ativador','Periodicidade']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if (row[1] == 'Email de Controlo da Maquina Interna de Rotinas') and (row[3] == '1 Dia'):
            print('ESTA TOP!')
            row[2] = 'x'
            cur.updateRow(row)

print ('Script Rotina da Maquina Interna - Periodicidade: Rotina de 1 Dia Finalizada')
```